# we are creating ecr repository using terraform. i created repos using for each. i am trying to attach policy. i am unable to use repo in resource

Tags: foreach, terraform, amazon-ecr

we are creating ecr repository using terraform. i created repos using for each.  i am trying to attach policy. i am unable to use repo in resource

tfvars file

```
app_ecr_repo = [
  { name = "project-1" },
  { name = "project-2" }
]
```

using for each we are taking two repo names

```
module "ecr" {
  source = "../../modules/ecr"

  # Common
  default_tags = var.default_tags

  # ECR
  for_each = { for repos in var.app_ecr_repo : join("-", [repos.name]) => repos }
  ecr_respositories = [
    {
      repo_name              = each.value.name
      lifecycle_policy_file  = "ecr_policy_01_tagged.json"
      image_tag_mutability   = "IMMUTABLE"
      image_scanning_enabled = true
    }
  ]
}
```

how to attach ecr repository name here

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy" {
  repository =  module.ecr.name

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "new policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

This is root module. He we passed resources for aws_ecr_repository

############################################################################################################

## Elastic Container Registry (ECR)

############################################################################################################

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository" "this" {
  count = length(var.ecr_respositories) > 0 ? length(var.ecr_respositories) : 0

  name                 = lookup(var.ecr_respositories[count.index], "repo_name", null)
  image_tag_mutability = lookup(var.ecr_respositories[count.index], "image_tag_mutability", var.image_tag_mutability)

  image_scanning_configuration {
    scan_on_push = lookup(var.ecr_respositories[count.index], "image_scanning_enabled", var.image_scanning_enabled)
  }

  tags = merge(
    {
      "Name" = lookup(var.ecr_respositories[count.index], "repo_name", null)
    },
    var.tags,
    var.default_tags
  )
}

############################################################################################################
# ECR Lifecycle Policy
############################################################################################################

locals {
  ecr_respositories_with_policy = [
    for repo in var.ecr_respositories :
    repo
    if lookup(repo, "lifecycle_policy_file", null) != null
  ]
}

resource "aws_ecr_lifecycle_policy" "this" {
  count      = length(local.ecr_respositories_with_policy) > 0 ? length(local.ecr_respositories_with_policy) : 0
  policy     = file("${path.cwd}/ecr_lifecycle_policy/${local.ecr_respositories_with_policy[count.index].lifecycle_policy_file}")
  repository = local.ecr_respositories_with_policy[count.index].repo_name

  depends_on = [aws_ecr_repository.this]
}
```

Comment: Are you using any outputs in the ECR module?

Comment: Also, can you add the name of the `aws_resource_repository` resource withing the module?

Comment: Not added resource ` aws_resource_repository`  in root main module

Comment: Without having the real name of the resource from the module it is hard to guess what it is so my answer might appear as not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to access the attributes of the resources created using modules, the child module has to have an output defined [1]. Accessing the child module output [2] is a bit different compared to outputs defined without using modules. So, in the child module code, you would have to add the following:

```
output "ecr_name" {
  description = "ECR repository name."
  value       = aws_ecr_repository.this.name
}
```

Since the module was invoked by using the `for_each` meta-argument, in the policy, you would say something like:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy" {
  for_each   = { for repos in var.app_ecr_repo : join("-", [repos.name]) => repos }
  repository = module.ecr[each.key].ecr_name

.
.
.
}
```

Referring to module instances is described in [3].

### EDIT

The child module is using the `count` meta-argument and the root module is using `for_each` meta-argument. Because of that, it is hard to map between the output of the module and the input required in the `aws_ecr_repository_policy` resource and make it dynamic. The only way this could work is:

a) Hardcoding the value of the key for the resource created with the module, e.g., `repository = module.ecr["project-1"].ecr_name[count.index]`, along with the `count` meta-argument set to `count = length(module.ecr["project-1"].ecr_name)`. This would have to be repeated for `project-2`.

b) Hardcoding the value of the index for the output and using the same `for_each`, i.e., `for_each = { for repos in var.app_ecr_repo : join("-", [repos.name]) => repos }` and the `repository = module.ecr[each.key].ecr_name[0]`

The second case is a bit better, but only because in the module call currently a list with one element gets passed:

```
  ecr_respositories = [
    {
      repo_name              = each.value.name
      image_tag_mutability   = "IMMUTABLE"
      image_scanning_enabled = true
    }
  ]
```

If the number of elements would be increased, the solution would not work and there would have to be multiple instances of `aws_ecr_repository_policy` resource. Additionally, the resource could be added to the module itself which could help avoiding these headaches.

**Solution 1**

In the root module, add this:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy" {
  for_each = { for repos in var.app_ecr_repo : join("-", [repos.name]) => repos }
  repository = module.ecr[each.key].ecr_name[0]

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "new policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

**Solution 2**

In the child module, add the following code:

```
resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy" {
  count = length(var.ecr_respositories) > 0 ? length(var.ecr_respositories) : 0
  repository = aws_ecr_repository.this[count.index].name

  policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "new policy",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
                "ecr:BatchGetImage",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:PutImage",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DeleteRepository",
                "ecr:BatchDeleteImage",
                "ecr:SetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DeleteRepositoryPolicy"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}
```

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs#declaring-an-output-value

[2] https://www.terraform.io/language/values/outputs#accessing-child-module-outputs

[3] https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#referring-to-instances

Comment: ```  
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 35, in resource "aws_ecr_repository_policy" "repo_policy":
│   35:   repository = module.ecr[each.key].ecr_name
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.key is a string, known only after apply
│     │ module.ecr is a map of object, known only after apply
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "ecr_name".

```

Comment: I need to see the way the ECR repository is called in the root module otherwise you will get the error.

Comment: In my query, I included root module. You can look here for further information.

Comment: Ok, so now the code is updated. You need to add the `output ecr_name` to the **child** module outputs, not the root one.

Comment: for output it's working. but now quetion is `aws_ecr_repository_policy` how to add repository from module. what you given code is it's not working

Comment: It does not work as you are using `for_each` and `count` interchangeably. Because of that, in the policy you have to hardcode either a) the module key based on the variable used in `for_each` or b) the index of the repository created with the `count` meta-argument.